# no me deja crear el ejecutable

Tags: python

es un código de python con el cual use kivy y funciona, pero cuando intento hacer el ejecutable con pyinstaller se crean las carpetas y el .spec pero a la hora crear el exe me salta este error
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
[10536] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!**

Comment: Con la única información de la pregunta puedo deducir que no se tienes el módulo kivy instalado o no se importó.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.